# What does "pts/" in the output of w mean?

Tags: command-line, ssh, security

When I run `w` -  to see who is logged on and what they are doing, i see this:

```
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
 user  tty7     :0               08:14   10:32m 44:10   0.50s gnome-session
 user  pts/0    :0.0             09:15    9:30m  0.24s  0.24s /bin/bash
 user  pts/1    :0.0             14:14    4:32m  0.20s  0.20s bash
 user  pts/5    :0.0             18:27    9:24   0.28s  0.28s bash
 user  pts/7    :0.0             18:35    9:57   0.40s  0.40s bash
 user  pts/8    :0.0             18:37    0.00s  0.22s  0.00s w
```

What are the `pts/` ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Pseudo-Terminal Slave

> #### Name
>
> ptmx, pts - pseudoterminal master and slave
>
> #### Description
>
> The file
> */dev/ptmx* is a character file with major number 5 and minor number 2,
> usually of mode 0666 and owner.group of root.root. It is used to
> create a pseudoterminal master and slave pair.
>
> When a process opens */dev/ptmx*, it gets a file descriptor for a
> pseudoterminal master (PTM), and a pseudoterminal slave (PTS) device
> is created in the */dev/pts* directory. Each file descriptor obtained by
> opening */dev/ptmx* is an independent PTM with its own associated PTS,
> whose path can be found by passing the descriptor to *[ptsname](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ptsname)(3)*.
>
> Before opening the pseudoterminal slave, you must pass the master's
> file descriptor to *[grantpt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/grantpt)(3)* and *[unlockpt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/unlockpt)(3)*.
>
> Once both the pseudoterminal master and slave are open, the slave
> provides processes with an interface that is identical to that of a
> real terminal.
>
> Data written to the slave is presented on the master descriptor as
> input. Data written to the master is presented to the slave as input.
>
> In practice, pseudoterminals are used for implementing terminal
> emulators such as *[xterm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm)(1)*, in which data read from the pseudoterminal
> master is interpreted by the application in the same way a real
> terminal would interpret the data, and for implementing remote-login
> programs such as *[sshd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd)(8)*, in which data read from the pseudoterminal
> master is sent across the network to a client program that is
> connected to a terminal or terminal emulator.
>
> Pseudoterminals can also be used to send input to programs that
> normally refuse to read input from pipes (such as *[su](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su)(1)*, and
> *[passwd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/passwd)(1)*).

**Source:** http://linux.die.net/man/4/pts

They're *usually* xterminal/gnome-terminal/terminator sessions.

Answer (score 6):

pts/ refers to a pseudo terminal (one that is not a physical terminal),  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_%28Unix%29