# what is pts/0 , :0 and attributes before it + ,? etc

Tags: command-line, tty, who

While reading about Linux, I got a `$ who -a`, so before trying that I logged into three of my text terminals `(tty1,tty2,tty3)` respectively,, and then I came back to `X-window` (Ctrl + Alt +f7),,
then I tried:-

```
$ who
anupam   tty2         2014-09-20 16:19
anupam   tty3         2014-09-20 16:20
anupam   tty1         2014-09-20 16:18
anupam   :0           2014-09-20 16:14 (:0)
anupam   pts/0        2014-09-20 16:21 (:0)
$ whoami
anupam
$ who -a
           system boot  2014-09-20 16:13
           run-level 2  2014-09-20 16:13
LOGIN      tty4         2014-09-20 16:13               736 id=4
LOGIN      tty5         2014-09-20 16:13               740 id=5
anupam   - tty2         2014-09-20 16:19 00:01        3200
anupam   - tty3         2014-09-20 16:20   .          3346
LOGIN      tty6         2014-09-20 16:13               752 id=6
anupam   - tty1         2014-09-20 16:18 00:02        3044
anupam   ? :0           2014-09-20 16:14   ?          1835 (:0)
anupam   + pts/0        2014-09-20 16:21   .          3455 (:0)
$
```

I am not getting some terms in `second attribute` (`- tty2,-tty 3,-tty1`i [why `-` is there in front of them?]) `?:0` (I guess it is indicating my `X-window` startup [why is there a `?` before `:0`?]), and values at fourth attribute `[00:01, ., 00:02, ?, .]?`

I tried to look at `$ man who -a`, but I didn't got these explanation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- `pts/0` is a **Pseudo-Terminal Slave** (See [What does "pts/" in the output of w mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25470/what-does-pts-in-the-output-of-w-mean)).
- The `(:0)` tells you which display you're using.
- the `+,-,?` tells you  whether a user/tty is accepting messages. If true, display a `+` for each user if `mesg y`, a `-` if `mesg n`, or a `?` if their tty cannot be stat'ed.

  See the `mesg` man page:

  > ```
  > NAME
  >        mesg - control write access to your terminal
  >
  > SYNOPSIS
  >        mesg [y|n]
  >
  > DESCRIPTION
  >        Mesg  controls  the  access to your terminal by others.  It's typically
  >        used to allow or disallow other users to write to  your  terminal  (see
  >        write(1)).
  >
  > OPTIONS
  >        y      Allow write access to your terminal.
  >
  >        n      Disallow write access to your terminal.
  >
  >        If no option is given, mesg prints out the current access state of your
  >        terminal.
  > ```

Source: [who.c](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/utopic/coreutils/utopic/view/head:/src/who.c)

Comment: Thanx @Sylvain Pineau,,well what does it mean to accept a message,,because when I am running $who -a in text terminals I am always getting (-) only ,no (+) ,,and  ? is always with (:0)??

Comment: @jazz: I've added info about the `mesg` command

Comment: I would say "stat'ed" instead of "stated" since the latter is kind of confusing

Comment: @nneonneo fixed, thx