# SSH session alway active, what is it? Should I close it?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, security, cinnamon, x2go

I've been trying to setup a server-> client local network with x2go.  I have it working, sort of... but I don't know much about networking, SSH, etc -- so it's been a steep learning curve.

I'm wanting to make my server/client as secure as I can. Currently I'm trying to figure out if the SSH connections that exist on my client are a part of x2go client, and/or if they should always be running.

I've used the command `who` and even if `x2go` is not running I still have two events running under my client user name. One is: `:0` (display 0?) and the other is: `pts/2`

And if I enter the terminal command: `ps -ef | grep ssh`  I get the following results that are running under my username (not root):

```
3822  3738  0 13:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch cinnamon-session-cinnamon  
7509  5048  0 13:27 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

Can you tell me what these are for and if I need them?  And if not, how to I get rid of them?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 1):

According to your output SSH is not running. SSH agent is software to hold private keys and is a helper. `ps -ef | grep ssh` shows there's no SSH active and `grep --color=auto ssh` is a result from your grep command and does not mean that SSH is active.

Comment: That's helpful. Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you're logged in to the GUI (as `:0` indicates), then of course you will have two entries in `who`: one for the GUI session, and one for the terminal you have opened to run `who`. Try the `w` command for a bit more detail:

```
$ who
muru  :0           2015-08-03 05:31 (:0)
muru  pts/0        2015-08-03 05:32 (:0)
muru  pts/1        2015-08-04 22:53 (:0)
muru  pts/2        2015-08-03 05:32 (:0)
muru  pts/3        2015-08-05 23:15 (:0)
$ w
 02:37:56 up 2 days, 21:06,  5 users,  load average: 0.60, 0.84, 0.87
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
muru  :0        Mon05   ?xdm?  14:21m  0.34s gnome-session
muru  pts/0     Mon05    7:02m  0.07s  1:42  /usr/bin/python2 /usr/sbin/terminator
muru  pts/1     Tue22    1:55   0.82s  0.82s ssh -R *:2022:localhost:22 lab
muru  pts/2     Mon05    2.00s  0.23s  0.00s w
muru  pts/3     23:15   23:56   0.68s  0.68s /bin/zsh
```

I have one Terminator terminal open with four tabs, and accordingly I have four additional entries in `w` and `who`.

Related:

- [What does "pts/" in the output of w mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25470/what-does-pts-in-the-output-of-w-mean)
- [what is pts/0 and (:0.0) in linux by type who am i](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/72177/70524) on Unix & Linux.

Comment: So it appears that this is normal.  Thanks.  (Also, I appreciate the edits you did to my initial question -- I will try and remember to use those features next time I enter a command.)

Comment: @TJK credit to heemayl. I didn't even notice that your output consisted of two lines.